# How to use sanctum for both SPA Authentication & mobile Authentication (via api)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-api

How to use sanctum for both **SPA Authentication** & **mobile Authentication** (via api) ?

api.php :

```
Route::get('test',function(){
 return Auth::user()->id;
});
```

when i access **/api/test** from the frontend (VueJs) it **works** i receive the user data.

when i access **/api/test** from the Postman or mobile application i get :

```
"message": "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object",
```

i already set token in the headers

when i change code to :

```
Auth::guard('sanctum')->user()->id;
```

it will work from PostMan and mobile app , but not working from the frontend

how can fix it ?

check if there is a session , login with web guard
and if there is a token in header use then sanctum token

Answer (score 0):

In Api.php  add (auth:sanctum)  middleware

Remember: send bearer token in  Axios request from vue js also from the postman

```
Route::get('test',function(){
 return Auth::user()->id;
})->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

or if need to get the id in the controller
try to get an id from a request like this

```
public function sendMessageToContacts(Request $request){
       $from=$request->user()->id;
}
```

[image]